# javascript promise resolve is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I try to use a promise, but am unable to return a proper resolve object.

my promise is:

```
function retrievecount(id, type) {
    var dfrd = $.Deferred();
    var hits = "the result";
    dfrd.resolve(hits);
    return dfrd.promise();
}
```

And I call this with:

```
 retrievecount(id, type)
    .then(function(hits) {
        //do stuff with the hits object
    });
```

But whenever I run this code I get the error:

"dfrd.resolve is not a function"

I tried:

```
   hits => dfrd.resolve(hits);
```

and

```
 dfrd.resolve=hits;
```

and a whole lot more, but I just can't get it working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. Also you can do `return dfrd.resolve(hits);` without creating a new promise.

Comment: Please, create an example where the problem can be replicated. Just pasting code and saying "this don't works for me" is not enough. Please, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and use Stack Snippets: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but see my answer below, the problem was not in my resolve but somewhere else in the code. However, I'm now unable to delete the question and bait for downvotes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems the problem was in some mistake in the actual code where dfrd was changed into another type of variable along the way. Typical javascript non-typesafety. I fixed it by changing the variable name.

The actual code was written by somebody else and obviously a lot more complex with nested promisses and calls to libraries, not really something you can post on S.O..

Answer (score -2):

I ran your code and found no issue. Check here
https://jsfiddle.net/shahzadfatehali/mjtw81o3/

```
function retrievecount(id, type) {
    var dfrd = $.Deferred();
    var hits = "the result";
    dfrd.resolve(hits);
    return dfrd.promise();
}

retrievecount(5, "new_type")
    .then(function(hits) {
        console.log(hits);
    });
```

Is there any other piece of code missing?

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.